# SimpleDateFormat parsing troubles

Tags: android, date, simpledateformat

I'm having trouble parsing a date that I'm trying to reformat. The SimpleDateFormat is giving me a real headache.

I'm getting this date from a news feed:

```
Wed, 06 Mar 2013 09:22:00 +0100
```

And I need to format it to this:

```
06.03.2013
```

I could just use a hashmap with all the months but I would like to use the SimpleDateFormat, since that's what it's for.

But I can't seem to find the right pattern.

Comment: Do you know the format you receive? What is +0100 at the end?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding following code snippet:--

```
    //SimpleDateFormat fmt = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE, dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss +SSSS");
SimpleDateFormat fmt = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE, dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss +SSSS", Locale.ENGLISH);
        Date date = null;
        try {
            date = fmt.parse("Wed, 06 Mar 2013 09:22:00 +0100");//Hardcoded for your case...
        } catch (ParseException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        SimpleDateFormat fmtOut = new SimpleDateFormat("dd.MM.yyyy");

        System.out.println("Date :-- " +fmtOut.format(date));
```

Comment: thx. i tried your snippet but am getting a NPE wenn trying to Log. Even with hardcoded string.

Comment: Well, I checked running the code here, and it worked fine, try copy-paste the given code as given i did made some changes earlier, .. Are you getting ParseException in catch block provided..

Comment: ok, i will, although i think i had the latest verion. but i'll still give it a new go incase im missing something. No the Exception throws in your last line, wich i btw i changed to an Log statement, but that shouldnt matter, right?

Comment: hmm, you are not getting ParseException means your date object returned not null, and still NPE.. weird, plz double check with first line of code snipet matches exactly , also check in logtrace for ParseException if any..

Comment: sry, your right, I am getting ParseException! java.text.ParseException: Unparseable date: "Wed, 06 Mar 2013 09:22:00 +0100" (at offset 0). here is how i implementet it atm http://pastebin.com/vsFNAYzN

Comment: obviously im getting the NPE becouse the inital parse turns out null..but why with me and not at your end?

Comment: ok, seems i have to pass the right Locale to the SimpleDateFormat, checking which one now

Comment: Thx, works with Locale.US. Edited your anwser to be correct for future reader, Thx Alot

Comment: @CRUSADER `S` is for milliseconds, the timezone is `z`, `Z`, or `X`, in this case `Z` I think.